# Why back propagation for Conv in tensorflow are separated into two operations?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to implement a custom convolution operation in tensorflow with c++ and cuda, and I found that the back-propagation for the Conv2D in tensorflow are implemented via [two separate operations.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1fc046c3a8eb62690cd78a6da1b62463e9133f6d/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_grad_ops.h#L23) Indeed, I found there are two operation implementations, namely [conv_grad_filter_ops.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_grad_filter_ops.cc) and [conv_grad_input_ops.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_grad_input_ops.cc) in the tensorflow source code, which means the gradients for filter and input are calculated respectively. May I ask what is the idea behind this implementation? Why they were not simply merged together as one single operation?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I did a test and found that there's about 30% speed boost if the back propagation for different inputs are split into different TF ops compared with wrapped into one single TF op. This is against intuition, perhaps there's something related with TF's architecture. Note: my test was based on CUDA im2col/col2im with CuBLAS instead of CuDNN.